# how to iterate through a csv file in neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, graph-databases

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saurabhkumar1903/neo4j/master/alterFile/sampletestoutput1.csv

here's the link to an image showning my expected output:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fYrA.jpg I've drawn it on paper just to show the expected output.

[I have a csv file containing a list of nodes where each line denotes a relationship of node at line[0] with every other list of nodes line[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKkIA.jpg),line[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKkIA.jpg),line[3].....line[4500] in that line]

eg. 
    1,3,4,5,7,8

```
2,4,5,11

4,10,11,15
```

here node at 
`line[0] i.e. "1" has a directed relationship with 
nodes at line[2] i.e "3" as a friend,
nodes at line[4], i,e."4" as a friend,
nodes at line[6], i,e."5" as a friend,`

what i am trying to do is I want to show a graph in neo4j dipicting the suggested friend relationship among each nodes.

what I cannot figure out is how to iterate the whole csv file as well as capture the relationship among each nodes on each line of csv file.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do Can you give a more explicit example of what you have in your CSV (an extract) and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: First of all, in Neo4j line[0] means column 0 of the currently read CSV live (provided you wrote 'AS line' in your instruction)


Would this CYpher solve your issue
MATCH (p0:Person{id:line[0]}),(p1:Person{id:line[0]})
CREATE (p0)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(p1)

Still, I agree with @logisima, you should be more explicit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure there is a `HAS_FRIEND` relationship between a person whose `id` comes first (in `line`) and the people whose ids come afterwards (in the same `line`), something like this should work:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///friends.csv' AS line
MERGE (p:Person {id: TOINT(line[0])})
FOREACH(id IN line[1..] |
  MERGE(f:Person {id: TOINT(id)})
  MERGE (p)-[:HAS_FRIEND]-(f))
```

This query presumes that you only want a single `HAS_FRIEND` relationship between any 2 nodes. Therefore, the `MERGE` for the relationship does not specify a direction. That way, if there is already such a relationship in *either* direction, no new relationship is created.

Also, the `TOINT` function is used to convert the id values to integers (since `LOAD CSV` automatically treats all values as strings). If you don't need that conversion, then you can remove the function calls.